# MySQL - Automatic copying data from one column to another in one table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to automatically copy data from one column to another in one table.

The following query does this, but not automatically:

```
UPDATE table SET columnB = columnA
```

Could someone show a trigger for this (that does it automatically)?

Note: columnB and columnA are integers.

Comment: Why 2 columns which are always the same I wonder.

Answer (score -1):

Should be as simple as:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER before_table_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SET new.columnB = new.columnA;
END //
delimiter ;
```

Be aware, this will only effect UPDATE's. You will need to copy this trigger for inserts as well `before_table_insert BEFORE INSERT`...

Comment: That trigger doesn't work. create trigger before_table_update before update on obligations for each row begin set user_id = id; end
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end
 create trigger before_table_update before update on obligations for each ro' at line 1

Comment: Note: table name is 'obligations' and attributes are: 'id' and 'user_id'. Could you point out why that doesn't work?

Comment: Also, after: delimiter $$ create trigger before_table_update before update on obligations for each row begin set user_id = id; end delimiter ; nothing changes.